# C# Lambda - are these two forms the same?

Tags: c#

I have seen this notation from time to time but do not understand it. I am looking at the [davidwest/TreeCollections](https://github.com/davidwest/TreeCollections/wiki/Creating-Your-First-Entity-Tree) Nuget package and the following syntax is used (I think there is a closing parenthesis missing):

```
root.Build(dataRoot, dataNode => new Category(dataNode.Id, dataNode.Name));
```

What is happening with this part of the line:

```
dataNode => new Category(dataNode.Id, dataNode.Name)
```

Is this functionally the same as:

```
var dataNode = new Category(dataNode.Id, dataNode.Name);
root.Build(dataRoot, dataNode);
```

What is happening here?

Comment: That is a C# lambda. I recommend finding some good documentation. `dataNode => new Category(dataNode.Id, dataNode.Name)` is an inline function which takes a single parameter `dataNode`, and returns a `Category`

Comment: I think the second parameter is called during traverse across the hierarchical data to create node

Comment: On the first example, a parenthesis seems to be missing, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided sample code I suppose you are calling the [following Build overload](https://github.com/davidwest/TreeCollections/blob/master/TreeCollections/src/TreeCollections/Tree/ItemTree/ItemTreeBuildExtensions.cs#L90):

```
public static void Build<TNode, TItem, TSNode>(this TNode parent, 
                                               TSNode sourceParent, 
                                               Func<TSNode, TItem> mapToItem, 
                                               int? maxRelativeDepth = null)
    where TNode : ItemTreeNode<TNode, TItem>
    where TSNode : SerialTreeNode<TSNode>, new()
{
    if (maxRelativeDepth <= 0) return;

    Build(parent, sourceParent, sp => sp.Children, mapToItem, maxRelativeDepth);
}
```

So, your `dataNode => new Category(dataNode.Id, dataNode.Name)` code is passed to the `Build` method as the `mapToItem` paramater.

The type of the `mapToItem` is `Func<TSNode, TItem>` which means it is a function which accepts a `TSNode` and will return `TItem`. In your case the `TItem` is a `Category`. (In the bellow code snippets I assume your `TSNode` is a `DataNode`)

So your above lambda expression has the following equivalents:

```
Func<DataNode, Category> mapper = dataNode => new Category(dataNode.Id, dataNode.Name);
```

```
Category mapTo(DataNode dataNode)
{
    return new Category(dataNode.Id, dataNode.Name);
}
```

---

So, basically you have provided a function to the library that will be called whenever a `TSNode` [needs to be mapped](https://github.com/davidwest/TreeCollections/blob/master/TreeCollections/src/TreeCollections/Tree/ItemTree/ItemTreeBuildExtensions.cs#L146).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in the [davidwest/TreeCollections](https://github.com/davidwest/TreeCollections/wiki/Creating-Your-First-Entity-Tree) website.
The parenthesis is missing in the example :

```
root.Build(dataRoot, dataNode => new Category(dataNode.Id, dataNode.Name);
```

But in every occurence of `root.build` inside the code provided in the Demo [source code of the nuget package](https://github.com/davidwest/TreeCollections/archive/refs/heads/master.zip), it is present :

```
root.Build(dataRoot, n => new CategoryItem(n.CategoryId, n.Name));
```

```
root.Build(dataRoot, n => new DualStateCategoryItem(n.CategoryId, n.Name));
```

```
root.Build(dataRoot, d => new CategoryItem(d.CategoryId, d.Name), n => !n.Name.StartsWith("c", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```